# Why is stylesheet causing my Bootstrap card carousel to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found a code pen example of a card carousel that I want to use. However, the bootstrap stylesheet is making the carousel not work properly. When I remove the style sheet the carousel works but it changes the style of that page which I need it to be consistent with my other pages.

This is the code pen example I used for the carousel card. https://codepen.io/kreigd/pen/ybYNoN

I used codes exactly that is shown in the example in the link above

```
<!-- I can only keep the 2 style sheet below and maintain my personal styling 
but the card carousel will not work--> 

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- or I remove the 2 above and add this. This makes the card carousel 
work but my personal styling will be changed and not consistent with my 
other pages -->

<link rel='stylesheet' 
href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css'>
```

I would need help in allowing me to keep my original styling and at the same time get the carousel card to work.

Comment: Are you getting any `console` error?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: 08DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js.map
events.html:228 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

This is the error i see on the console

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v4.3.1

Comment: I am also seeing this error

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js.map

Answer (score 0):

Which ever is declared or called the latest, the style property depends on it. Some properties you have in `<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and `<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` will be the same as the on you're using for you Carousel.

There can be only one solution, either you have to provide the css properties that are meant for the carousel to work by picking them from the bootstrap or you've to delete the unnecessary properties from the carousel bootstrap which are affecting the main design of your page.

Comment: I tried pulling out all the carousel related css and adding into a separate css but it does not seem to work. I am unsure which are the components i would need to pull out

Comment: Even I had the same issue for one of my project. I was able to clear it with one of the above method I told. Someone will surely help you.